# Bogus widget in Qt Creator

Tags: qt

I'm a Qt newbie, working in Qt Creator 3.1.2 (Ubuntu Linux), Qt 5.3.1.

My program has a form with a button (`pushButton`) which changes the value of a text field (`plainTextEdit`) on being pressed. Both `pushButton` and `plainTextEdit` have been added in graphical mode. Connection between the button and its slot (`on_pushButton_clicked()`) has been set up via the graphical interface too.

The problem is, the program produces a bogus `plainTextEdit`, i.e. a different one, in the upper left corner, where the output goes to, while the "main" one stays clean. The question hence is, how I can avoid it? In general, how should I connect graphical widgets and their counterparts in the code? Here is my program:

**mainwindow.h:**

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QPlainTextEdit>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow 
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

public slots:
    void on_pushButton_clicked();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;

    QPushButton *pushButton;
    QPlainTextEdit *plainTextEdit;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

**main.cpp**:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

**mainwindow.cpp**:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    plainTextEdit = new QPlainTextEdit(this);
    // whenever I remove the previous line, I get SIGSEGV
    setWindowTitle(tr("My test app..."));
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    plainTextEdit->setPlainText("Some text here");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the widget you're creating in your constructor that is "bogus". The widgets you created in the forms editor belong to the `Ui::MainWindow`, you must not re-create them in your main window.

Remove this from your `MainWindow`:

```
QPushButton *pushButton;
QPlainTextEdit *plainTextEdit;
```

Remove the widget creation from the constructor:

```
plainTextEdit = new QPlainTextEdit(this);
```

Change your `on_pushButtonClicked` member to:

```
ui->plainTextEdit->setPlainText("Some text here");
```